# Podio API image upload on item

Tags: php, podio

Hoping I can get some help here. I am able to upload image files via the API, and I receive a file_id as a response, but every time I try to update an image field in an item using the id that was returned I get:

```
"File with mimetype application/octet-stream is not allowed, must match one of (MimeTypeMatcher('image', ('png', 'x-png', 'jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'gif', 'bmp', 'x-ms-bmp')),)
```

I've even added a line of code into my PHP script to pull the jpeg from file, rewrite it as a jpeg to be certain ( imagejpeg()) before uploading. Still, when I get to the point of updating the image field on the item, I get the same error. It seems all images uploaded via the API are converted to octet-stream. How do I get around this?
I'm using the Podio PHP library.

The PHP code is as follows:

```
$fileName = "testUpload.jpeg";
imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($fileName)),$fileName);
$goFile = PodioFile::upload($fileName,$itemID);
$fileID = $goFile->file_id;

PodioItem::update((int)$itemID, array(
        'fields' => array(
            "logo" => (int)$fileID,
        )
    ) , array(
        "hook" => 0
    ));
```

Comment: can you please provide example source code which is causing this error?

Comment: I think I can see the error. In the initial PodioFile::upload, do I need to include file type extension in the second parameter? I'm using an itemID as the "name" parameter in the function.

Comment: Yes, you are right, filename should have file extension as well, I've modified answer. Please accept it, so other people could benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try and replace :

```
$goFile = PodioFile::upload($fileName,$itemID);
```

with something like:

```
$goFile = PodioFile::upload('/path/to/example/file/example.jpg', 'example.jpg');
$fileID = $goFile->file_id;
PodioItem::update((int)$itemID, array(
    'fields' => array(
        "logo" => array((int)$fileID),
    )
```

As it is described in https://developers.podio.com/examples/files#subsection_uploading 
And then use `$fileID` as you've used. And yes, `filename` should have file extension as well, so it will not work with just `123123123` but should work well with `123123123.jpg`